# What does the map choice depends on?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In World of Tanks,

There is a number of maps and when you want to play the match making system simply assign you one. It seems to be not totally random. For exemple, when you play tier 1 or 2 tanks, you will often get some maps that you simply *won't* get at all while playing tier 5 or 6.

How does the Match making pick the map you will play on? Is it chosen whit the tank's tiers of the players? Does it depends on the number of artilery or some weird if statements like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower tier tanks will only play on a limited subset of maps, to give players the chance to familiarize themselves with them quickly.

**Battle Tiers 1 and 2 fight on these maps:**

- Malinovka
- Himmelsdorf
- Mines
- Province

**Battle Tier 3 additionally fights on these maps:**

- Karelia
- Prokhorovka
- Ensk

The province map is not available for Tier 4 and above. For Tier 4 and above the map picked should be random, but in practice this is not the case. The reasons behind this are not completely clear, although wargaming does seem to give new maps a higher chance of appearing.

See [this forum thread on map distribution stats](http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/86329-map-distribution/) for more information on the actual frequency of appearance of some maps.

Comment: I love how well-informed you are and how fast you answer pretty much all of my questions. Thanks! +1

Comment: What about [Pearl River](http://worldoftanks.com/news/2159-tour-pearl-river/)?

Comment: No stats for that one yet, think it's been too short since the release to have enough data but keep watching the thread and it should show up there soon enough

Comment: Absent stats, there is a lot of anecdotal discussion that Pearl River is showing up very rarely. I've only seen it twice since 8.5, despite seeing the other new additions (assault on Prokhorovka and the changed assault version of Sand River) several times each.